# How to make particles.js fullscreen in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, react-particles-js

Here is a link to a working example of the site: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-kapitsa-kk1ls

I have been trying to get the particles to travel the full height of the screen but I can not get them to go all the way to the bottom. I have tried changing the heights of different `<div>` elements and changing the way that the particles are rendered with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a width and height prop on the `Particles` component to be 100 percent of the view width and height. ([How to Use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-particles-js#how-to-use))

```
<Particles width='100vw' height="100vh" params={params} />
```

[image: Edit react-particles-js full height]